# keyboard height varies in ios8

Tags: ios, keyboard, ios8

Am using the below code to get keyboard height which varies in IPhone 5s device with ios8 compared to IPhone4s device with ios7 .As a result my textfield is moving very high when i tap on it in IPhone5s with ios8 while the same code works fine in IPhone 4s with ios7.Can someone guide how the problem can be fixed in both versions.

```
- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    NSDictionary* info = [notification userInfo];
    CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
    float kbHeight;
    if (([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation== UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)||([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation== UIDeviceOrientationPortrait))
    {
        kbHeight=kbSize.height;
    }
    else
    {
        kbHeight=kbSize.width;
    }



    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, kbHeight, 0.0);

    self.scroll.contentInset = contentInsets;
    self.scroll.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;

    CGRect rect = self.view.frame;
    rect.size.height -= (kbHeight);


    if (!CGRectContainsPoint(rect, self.activeField.frame.origin))
    {
        CGPoint scrollPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, self.activeField.frame.origin.y - ((kbHeight) - self.activeField.frame.size.height));
        [self.scroll setContentOffset:scrollPoint animated:NO];
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @Legoless I think the question is "Can somebody help me?" :)

Comment: yes as the keyboard height is varying  am facing some issues in my app..how can i get the actual height of the keyboard

Answer (score 2):

Simply Replace the line from your code

```
CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
```

With

```
CGSize kbSize = [[userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
```

Let me know if it works

Answer (score 1):

This is not an issue, you are getting different size keyboard because `Predictive` is `Enable`.

The height of keyboard is **216** which is fixed but when `Predictive` is Enabled you will get **253** as height.

[image]

So you have to write code for both conditions.

Comment: how to i get the height of keyboard when predictive text is on?

Comment: From same code, as i say in above answer if predictive is ON you will get 253 as height otherwise 216

Comment: try to run code after disabling predictive, you get consistent height

Comment: No, my friend 568 is not a height it is width in landscape mode. I also test your code in landscape mode, height of keyboard with predictive is 193 and without 162.

Answer (score 0):

use this code, may help you

```
- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification*)note {
      NSDictionary* info = [note userInfo];
      CGSize _kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
      float kbHeight = _kbSize.width > _kbSize.height ? _kbSize.height : _kbSize.width;
}
```

kbHeight variable stored height of the keyboard.