# Xcode 5 and iOS 8 keyboard scroll not working

Tags: xcode, ios7, scroll, ios8, keyboard

So to be to the point, when I build my project with Xcode 6, the components on my screen scroll up correctly when the keyboard is about to be shown.

However, when I build with Xcode 5, all components go off the screen (aka they move too high). I searched but I can't find  the problem.

This problem only occurs on iOS 8 in landscape mode. On iOS 7 everything works just fine. Does anyone have an idea what the problem is? It is mandatory to build with Xcode 5 for some reasons.
Thanks!

**When the view is created**

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardShown:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
```

**Event Handler**

```
- (void)keyboardShown:(NSNotification *)notification{
    CGSize kbSize = [[notification.userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
    float kbHeight = UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation) ? kbSize.height : kbSize.width;
    if( [[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion doubleValue] >= 8.0) kbHeight = kbSize.height;

    _origScrollIndicatorInsets = _legsTableView.scrollIndicatorInsets;
    _origContentInset = _legsTableView.contentInset;

    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, kbHeight, 0.0);
    _legsTableView.contentInset = contentInsets;
    _legsTableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;

    if (_activeTextField) {
        CGRect fieldRect = [_legsTableView convertRect:_activeTextField.bounds fromView:_activeTextField];
        [_legsTableView scrollRectToVisible:fieldRect animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From this post I've found my answer for calculation the height and this works perfectly.
[keyboard height varies in ios8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26971819/keyboard-height-varies-in-ios8?rq=1)

```
- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification*)note {
      NSDictionary* info = [note userInfo];
      CGSize _kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
      float kbHeight = _kbSize.width > _kbSize.height ? _kbSize.height : _kbSize.width;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The projects created and used in Xcode 6 are not always compatible with Xcode 5. Some of the things get changed like the storyboard and auto layout with Xcode 6. I don't see any reason to need it built in Xcode 5, I assume you are looking for backwards compatibility. You can then change your deployment target for that app. If you change it to 7, or an older iOS you will see how it works on older iOS but still built using the newest release.

[image]

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your comment. There are some other reason why I build with Xcode 5 for customers. But you are right I guess. I'm not using storyboards in my project. The deployment target is set to iOS 6.1 which is needed.

Comment: I figured it had to do with storyboards, if they are not being used I'm not sure. I would recommend developing in Xcode 5 for these applications and copying the file before opening in Xcode 6. This would make sure you can always revert back to the Xcode 5 version. usually Xcode can handle older versions easily, but modifications have to be made to handle a newer version.